# Evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(x)\cos(x)\ dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, improper-integrals

Why is
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(x)\cos(x)\thinspace \mathrm{d}x=0?$$
My textbook says it is so by symmetry, but it seems like using that logic, the integral of $\sin(x)$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ should also be $0$, but it is not.

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin x\cos x\,dx$ is not zero. It actually doesn't exist.

Comment: Throw away this textbook. $\sin x\cos x=\frac12\sin2x$.

Comment: I would have said that neither integral converged.  Or, rather, that to make sense of the problem you need to specify how the limits are being taken.

Comment: The integral is only zero in the “principle value” sense (as is the integral of $\sin(x)$ on the same interval). In the classic theory of integration, neither of the integrals exist.

Comment: You are right. Just use the formula for $\sin 2x$ and a change of variable, to relate the two integrals

Comment: It might be worthwhile to know what book you are using.  As @User8128 alludes, there are certain senses in which it can be said that the integral converges, though these require a particular context.  If this is meant to be a basic calculus text, and no further context is given, then you should find a better book.  But if the book is covering a different theory, then there may be additional definitions and theorems given which explain this apparent problem.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(x)\cos(x)\thinspace \mathrm{d}x=$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^0 \sin(x)\cos(x)\thinspace \mathrm{d}x+$$

$$\int_0^{\infty} \sin(x)\cos(x)\thinspace \mathrm{d}x$$

None of the last tow integrals exist, so $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(x)\cos(x)\thinspace \mathrm{d}x$$

Does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing we could write is
$$\int \sin(x)\cos(x)\,dx=-\frac{1}{2} \cos ^2(x)+C$$ making
$$\int_{-a}^{+a} \sin(x)\cos(x)\,dx=0$$